# Is there a music player that can play the sound from a youtube film?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, streaming

I want to play [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXqPYte8tvc) song but I don't want to see the video.

Is there a music player that can do that and please tell me how to do it?

*the youtube link is just an example, don't put too much interest in it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)**, of course.

1. Copy the URL of your video
2. Fire up VLC
3. Drop down menu: Media -> Open Network Stream
4. Paste the link including the http:// prefix and all
5. Press play
6. Drop down menu: Video -> Video track -> Disable

Done.

Just tested it (to be fair, *on Windows*, but I'm fairly sure that it works on any platform VLC runs on)

If you don't want to go through the whole copypasting process, there's always **[command line VLC](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man1/vlc.1.html)**.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I'm just a bit ashamed I didn't think of it myself (been using VLC for as long as I can remember).

Answer (score 1):

I havent found any player so far. But a script like the following works if you know the address of the actual video (and see zetahs answer on that topic):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import gobject
import pygst
pygst.require("0.10")
import gst

mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin2", "player")
fakesink = gst.element_factory_make("fakesink", "fakesink")
player.set_property("video-sink", fakesink)
player.set_property("uri", sys.argv[1])
player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
mainloop.run()
```

With the example video you have given, this would be launched like this (when saved as playme.py):

```
python playme.py "http://o-o.preferred.hansenet-dus1.v24.lscache2.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cratebypass%2Ccp&fexp=902906%2C903805%2C910010%2C913601&itag=22&ip=78.0.0.0&signature=97A0CA46B2546A28A4F44C217500330F0416A5A0.72FB211E73DBC1DEBFBA6816794BD8B0E680D191&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&expire=1321135200&key=yt1&ipbits=8&cp=U0hRRlFOU19FSkNOMV9JSFdDOkVVUkZVVW5yNXFJ&id=797a8f62d7bcb6f7"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Musictube [image: Install Musictube] is a YouTube music player.

[image]

- With it you can listen to millions of songs on YouTube in a convenient way, much like using a traditional player.
- Musictube plays album tracks in their original order and integrates album covers, artist pictures and lyrics.

It's available in the Software Centre (only on Ubuntu +11.10, AFAIK), it costs 8.99€ (11.99 $), but it's worth it. Nevertheless, you can [try it](http://flavio.tordini.org/files/musictube/musictube.deb) before buying it.
For more info, go to the [developer's website](http://flavio.tordini.org/musictube).

Comment: Worth noting from the link that this appears to be available in the Ubuntu Software Center, and it is also cross-platform.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise of that, thanks for the info.

Comment: I can't find it in the software center. And the links aren't valid.

Comment: I think it's not available in the Natty USC. However you can buy it from the developer's web.

Comment: IF I can't test it how is it a valid answer?

Comment: You can test it from the developer's web and also buy it. What you can't do is buying it within Ubuntu Natty.

Answer (score 1):

```
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KABUQxllGbk
mplayer -vo none KABUQxllGbk.webm
```

The programs youtube-dl and mplayer can do what you want, from the command line. You can install them both from the repositories. Then, when you want to listen to a video, you can download it using youtube-dl, and play it using mplayer. The "-vo none" command line output on mplayer will suppress the video (by forcing mplayer to not load a video driver), so it will just play the audio from the file.

Optionally, you can specify a filename and output directory for the file you download using the -o flag, so your files aren't labeled so cryptically.

Comment: I notice you are using a specific YouTube URL in your answer, which is just two lines of terminal commands with no description of how it works. Can you please elaborate on what exactly your answer does?

Comment: If I may, I think what Serge means is this: the first command downloads the video from YouTube, and the second command plays the song.

Answer (score 1):

I personally install adblock and block the video section - for example if someone posts a video here, I block the video first to vet the title, about and sound.

How to:

Click AdBlock and "Block and ad on this page"

[image]

Click the video

[image]

Slide it to the last one that will not hide anything else:

```
Blocked element:
<DIV
id="player"
class=" watch-medium " >
```

Go to the end of the slider and 3 back.

Then click looks good.

[image]

Finally click Block it.

[image]

As you can see, sound is still playing.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty clever, but it's not an audio player and it requires me to have my browser open. Sure not a big deal for most but not the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox as your web browser, there is a Greasemonkey script called KeepTube that will let you download mp3 files from YouTube videos. Install the Greasemonkey Firefox extension from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/?src=search) and then install the KeepTube userscript from [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/47636) and then close and reopen your YouTube tab.  Maybe this will help you, and hopefully I'm posting my suggestion correctly :)

Comment: I don't use firefox, it's too slow. I use Google Chrome.